# How do I set the record's position relative to a group in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a series of records that can be grouped by a `group_id`

Example records:

```
╭───╥──────────┬───────────────────╮
│id ║ group_id │ position_in_group │
╞═══╬══════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1 ║    2     │        null       │
│ 2 ║    1     │        null       │
│ 3 ║    1     │        null       │
│ 4 ║    1     │        null       │
│ 5 ║    2     │        null       │
│ 6 ║    2     │        null       │
│ 7 ║    3     │        null       │
│ 8 ║    3     │        null       │
│ 9 ║    3     │        null       │
└───╨──────────┴───────────────────┘
```

I want to set the `position_in_group` for each record. It is the position of the record inside the group if I `GROUP BY group_id`.

For example:
  In the group with id 1, the record with id=2 is the first, so its `position_in_group` would be 1.

The final table would be:

```
╭───╥──────────┬───────────────────╮
│id ║ group_id │ position_in_group │
╞═══╬══════════╪═══════════════════╡
│ 1 ║    2     │        1          │
│ 2 ║    1     │        1          │
│ 3 ║    1     │        2          │
│ 4 ║    1     │        3          │
│ 5 ║    2     │        2          │
│ 6 ║    2     │        3          │
│ 7 ║    3     │        1          │
│ 8 ║    3     │        2          │
│ 9 ║    3     │        3          │
└───╨──────────┴───────────────────┘
```

Is there any way I can do this in a SQL query?

Comment: This would be done using `row_number() over (partition by group_id order by id)` in oracle and sqlserver.   Check here for mysql equivalent options:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895110/6205293

Comment: yes, a query with variables ( @'s) ... someone bang one out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way to do this with pure SQL and without variables with a self JOIN:

```
UPDATE my_table
JOIN (
  SELECT c.aid AS id, COUNT(*)-1 AS position_in_group
  FROM (
    SELECT a.id AS aid, b.id AS bid, a.group_id 
    FROM my_table AS a
    JOIN my_table AS b ON (a.group_id=b.group_id AND a.id >= b.id)
  ) AS c
  GROUP BY c.aid
) AS d ON my_table.id = d.id
SET my_table.position_in_group = d.position_in_group;
```

I self join the table with itself to create matching pairs (records in the same group) without duplicate pairs. 
Then I just count those pairs grouping by the id of the left record.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use variables.  A bit challenging in MySQL, but it can look like this:

```
set @g := -1;
set @rn := 0;

update t
    set position_in_group = (@rn := if(@g = group_id, @rn + 1,
                                       if(@g := group_id, 1, 1)
                                      )
                            )
    order by group_id, id;
```

Note:  You need to initialize the variables separately from the `update` statement, because MySQL does not support joins and order by in the same `update` statement.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to store this data...

```
SELECT id
     , group_id
     , rank
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id
            , group_id
            , CASE WHEN group_id = @prev THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank 
            , @prev:=group_id prev 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=1,@prev:=null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY group_id
            , id
     ) a
 ORDER
    BY id;
```

...but if you really want to...

```
UPDATE my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id
            , group_id
            , CASE WHEN group_id = @prev THEN @i:=@i+1 ELSE @i:=1 END rank 
            , @prev:=group_id prev 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=1,@prev:=null) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY group_id
            , id
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   SET a.rank = b.rank;
```

Answer (score 0):

this solution was implemented by another user [abcdn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32105418/3762855) see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32105418/3762855

```
SELECT a.id, a.group_id, (
    SELECT count(*) from groups b where a.id >= b.id AND a.group_id = b.group_id
) AS row_number FROM groups a;
```